# Java rawImageInputStream cannot be cast -imageIO

Tags: java, javax.imageio, dcm4che

I am working on an image converter which converts images of DICOM format to a PNG format.

```
@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
    public void dcmconvpng(File file, int indice, File fileOutput)
            throws IOException {        
        ImageIO.scanForPlugins();
        Iterator<ImageReader> iter = ImageIO
                .getImageReadersByFormatName("DICOM");
        ImageReader readers = (ImageReader) iter.next();
        DicomImageReadParam param = (DicomImageReadParam) readers
                .getDefaultReadParam();

        ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(file);
        readers.setInput(iis, true);
        myPngImage = readers.read(indice, param);
        BufferedImage dimg = myPngImage;

        File myPngFile = fileOutput;
        OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                myPngFile));
        PNGEncodeParam.RGB param2 = new PNGEncodeParam.RGB();
        ImageEncoder enc = ImageCodec.createImageEncoder("PNG", output, param2);
        enc.encode(dimg);
        output.close();
        System.out.println("Conversion has been completed!");

    }
```

It has worked in the past - however since I have added jai_imageio-core-1.3.1.jar to my libraries (Which I require for an OCR system elsewhere in my project) I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.media.imageio.stream.RawImageInputStream cannot be cast to com.github.jaiimageio.stream.RawImageInputStream
    at com.github.jaiimageio.impl.plugins.raw.RawImageReader.setInput(RawImageReader.java:106)
    at javax.imageio.ImageReader.setInput(ImageReader.java:380)
    at org.dcm4che2.imageioimpl.plugins.dcm.DicomImageReader.initRawImageReader(DicomImageReader.java:371)
    at org.dcm4che2.imageioimpl.plugins.dcm.DicomImageReader.initImageReader(DicomImageReader.java:339)
    at org.dcm4che2.imageioimpl.plugins.dcm.DicomImageReader.read(DicomImageReader.java:530)
```

I am pretty sure that this is due to the multiple imageIO Jars I have in my project, any help please.

Comment: I have noticed that it does convert 3 images only, but doesn't do any more than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up scrapping the whole code block and used the following libraries instead:

- pixelmed.jar
- vecmath-1.5.2.jar

and used the following code:

```
public void dcmconvpng(File file, int indice, File fileOutput)
        throws IOException, DicomException {

    ConsumerFormatImageMaker.convertFileToEightBitImage(file.toString(),
            fileOutput.toString(), "png", indice);
}
```

It literally does the same thing, just much more easier.

Answer (score 1):

> I am pretty sure that this is due to the multiple imageIO Jars I have in my project

Spot on.

The problem seems to be that the `DicomImageReader` creates a new `RawImageInputStream` (from `com.sun.media.imageio.stream`), but does a *lookup* on the RAW `ImageReader`:

```
RawImageInputStream riis = new RawImageInputStream(...)
...
reader = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("RAW").next();
reader.setInput(riis);
```

(Code taken from [DicomImageReader.java, `initRawImageReader` method](https://github.com/dicomgrid/dcm4che2/blob/master/dcm4che-imageio/src/main/java/org/dcm4che2/imageioimpl/plugins/dcm/DicomImageReader.java)).

Because both of your JARs contain service providers (SPIs) for RAW image reading, and there's no specific ordering by default, the actual `ImageReader` the  `DicomImageReader` will use at runtime is undefined (but in the case of your stack trace, it's obviously the wrong one). The best solution for the long term, is probably that the `DicomImageReader` is updated to make sure it obtains the correct `RawImageReader` (one that is compatible with the input), but integrating such a change usually takes more time, so I'll outline a workaround below.

You write that you need both of the JARs in your project, but if you don't need the RAW image reader from both JARs, you could unregister the one from the `com.github.jaiimageio` package.

See [this answer for details on how to unregister or order SPIs at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38198991/1428606). The SPIs in that question are for TIFF format, but the concept is the same. You should unregister the `com.github.jaiimageio.impl.plugins.raw.RawImageReaderSpi`, or make sure the `com.sun.media.imageio.impl.plugins.raw.RawImageReaderSpi` is ordered first.

It's also possible to stop the SPIs inside the JAR from registering, by editing the entries in the `META-INF/services/` folder. There should be an entry for `META-INF/services/javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi`, and you should remove or comment out (using `#`) the `com.github.jaiimageio.impl.plugins.raw.RawImageReaderSpi`.

Comment: Hi haraldK, thank you for your response. I have tried to implement the methods you have provided in your other post to no avail, and continue to get the same error. I then commented out the line you suggested and the program still continued to produce the same error.

Comment: Just some more background. If the library jai-imageio-core-1.3.1.jar but keep jai_imageio-1.1.jar, my converter does run, however my other method which requires imageio then produces the error:
`NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/jaiimageio/plugins/tiff/TIFFImageWriteParam`

Comment: Are you running your application in a web container?

Comment: No I am not, I'm just using a regular Java console application.
This is my repo. https://github.com/mazenSehg/DIC2PNG

Comment: Hmm... I'm pretty confident that the workarounds I suggested works if implemented correctly. Could be that the `ImageIO.scanForPlugins()` re-adds the provider, or that there are more troublesome providers. But I'll just leave it then, if you have found a different way to solve it. :-)

Comment: Haha, I'm sure your method does work - it's most likely just me just me being a noob. Thank you for you help though!