# ImageIO.read is sporadically reading an image file

Tags: image, dicom, javax.imageio, dcm4che

I am using the following Java code to read a Dicom image, trying to convert it later to JPEG file. When the reading happens in the line

```
tempImage = ImageIO.read(dicomFile);
```

, the returned image either has an image type of 10 or something else, like 0 or 11. The problem here is that the reading happens sporadically. Sometimes the returned image type is 10, and sometimes it is not.
When the returned image type is 10, the writing of the converted JPEG file succeeds and returns true and I get my JPEG file. However, when the returned image type is not 10, the writing fails and returns false, and doesn't produce any file. This is the statement I am using for writing:

```
writerReturn = ImageIO.write(image, "jpeg", new File(tempLocation + studyId + File.separator + seriesUID + File.separator + objectId + thumbnail+ ".jpeg"));
```

I have spent long time trying to figure out why this sporadic behaviour is happening but couldn't reach to anything. Could you please help?

Comment: maybe the dicomFile is not encoded with a part 10 metaheader which conveys information about the format in which the image is stored? Can you provide an (anonymized) dump of the header here?

Comment: As a matter of fact, the conversion is sometimes successful and sometimes not, for the very same image. This link is a link for the DICOM image I am testing. As I mentioned, sometimes it gets converted to JPEG and sometimes not.

Comment: Sorry forgot to put the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lzm5xzmk7me3qug/1.2.840.113619.2.67.2200970061.29232060605151433.387?dl=0

Comment: Are you starting a new Java process for each attempt, or do you have some kind of server? If you restart the Java process/server, the order of ImageIO plugins might be shuffled, so if you have multiple plugins, this may be the issue. Try running the following with the same classpath as your conversion code: `Iterator<ImageReader> providers = IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance().getServiceProviders(ImageReaderSpi.class, true); while (providers.hasNext()) {System.out.println("provider: " + providers.next()); }` and report the result back.

Comment: I will and I will get back to you. Thanks a lot

Comment: Just to answer the first question, I am using a Glassfish server for running the application. I am receiving requests from a JMS queue in a servlet.

Comment: You are right. I ran the program 3 times. The first time, the image type was 11 and the conversion failed. This was the order of the printed Image Readers:

Comment: Sorry. The results are in this link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9d4w9alway1cm1u/ImageReader.txt?dl=0

Comment: So my question is: does the order makes a difference? Also, How can I know which Image Reader the application picked? Also, How can I force the application to use a certain Image Reader. Thanks a lot. You highlighted the source of the problem

Comment: I'm guessing that both `DicomImageReaderSpi` and `DcmImageReaderSpi` can read the image, however they return different image types. 10 is `TYPE_BYTE_GRAY`, while 11 is `TYPE_USHORT_GRAY` (which is 16 bit and can't be written as a JFIF compliant JPEG, as @malat points out). Luckily, you can control the order of the `ImageReaderSpi`s, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38198991/1428606) (the example shows TIFF plugins, but just replace with the names of your Spis, and it should work the same way).

Comment: Great. It is working fine. Thanks a lot. It turned out that the "org.dcm4che2.imageioimpl.plugins.dcm.DicomImageReaderSpi" is the image reader that is supposed to be used, and I deregistered "org.dcm4cheri.imageio.plugins.DcmImageReaderSpi". I suggest that you put your last as the answer, because it is the actual solution for the problem.

Comment: @WAELELMASSARANI Added my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From extra information in the comments, we have discovered that the application is running in a Glassfish server, and that **there are two ImageIO plugins installed**, both capable of reading DICOM images. The problem is not really related to reading, but sometimes writing the decoded image to JPEG fails.

The service providers for mentioned plugins are `org.dcm4cheri.imageio.plugins.DcmImageReaderSpi` and 
`org.dcm4che2.imageioimpl.plugins.dcm.DicomImageReaderSpi`, but only the latter (`DicomImageReaderSpi`) seems to work. This is because it produces an 8 bits per sample `BufferedImage`, which is what the `JPEGImageWriter` is able to write (the `DcmImageReaderSpi` creates a 16 bit per sample image, which can't be written as a JFIF JPEG and thus unsupported by the `JPEGImageWriter`).

Because of the (by default) unspecified (read: unpredictable) order of ImageIO plugins, the result is that sometimes you get the 8 bps version and sometimes the 16 bit version of the image, and the end result is that *sometimes* the conversion won't work.

---

Now, the good news is that we *can* **set an explicit order** of ImageIO plugins, or we can **unregister** plugins at runtime, to get a stable predictable result. What is the better of these options, depends on wether there are other code on your server that depends on the undesired plugin or not. If you don't need it, unregister it.

The code below shows both of the above options:

```
// Get the global registry
IIORegistry registry = IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance();

// Lookup the known providers
ImageReaderSpi goodProvider = lookupProviderByName(registry, "org.dcm4che2.imageioimpl.plugins.dcm.DicomImageReaderSpi");
ImageReaderSpi badProvider = lookupProviderByName(registry, "org.dcm4cheri.imageio.plugins.DcmImageReaderSpi");

if (goodProvider != null && badProvider != null) {
    // If both are found, EITHER
    // order the good provider BEFORE the bad one
    registry.setOrdering(ImageReaderSpi.class, goodProvider, badProvider);

    // OR
    // un-register the bad provider
    registry.deregisterServiceProvider(badProvider);
}
```

---

```
// New and improved (shorter) version. :-)
private static <T> T lookupProviderByName(final ServiceRegistry registry, final String providerClassName) {
    try {
        return (T) registry.getServiceProviderByClass(Class.forName(providerClassName));
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException ignore) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

You should also *make sure you run this code only once*, for a container-based application, a good time is at application context start-up.

With the above solution, `ImageIO.read(...)` will always use the good plugin, and `ImageIO.write(...)` will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing the issue is that your input image is 16bits while I am sure your code only accept 8bits input. You cannot write out using the so-called usual JPEG 8bits lossy format unless you transform your 16bits input.

On my box here is what I see:

```
$ gdcminfo 1.2.840.113619.2.67.2200970061.29232060605151433.387
MediaStorage is 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.1.1 [Digital X-Ray Image Storage - For Presentation]
TransferSyntax is 1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.90 [JPEG 2000 Image Compression (Lossless Only)]
NumberOfDimensions: 2
Dimensions: (1887,1859,1)
SamplesPerPixel    :1
BitsAllocated      :16
BitsStored         :14
HighBit            :13
PixelRepresentation:0
ScalarType found   :UINT16
PhotometricInterpretation: MONOCHROME2 
PlanarConfiguration: 0
TransferSyntax: 1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.90
Group           0x6000
Rows            1859
Columns         1887
NumberOfFrames  0
Description     
Type            G 
Origin[2]       1,1
FrameOrigin     0
BitsAllocated   1
BitPosition     0
Origin: (0,0,0)
Spacing: (0.187429,0.187429,1)
DirectionCosines: (1,0,0,0,1,0)
Rescale Intercept/Slope: (0,1)
Orientation Label: AXIAL
```

So if you want to convince yourself you could extract the encapsulated JPEG 2000 bytestream:

```
$ gdcmraw 1.2.840.113619.2.67.2200970061.29232060605151433.387 bug.j2k
$ file bug.j2k 
bug.j2k: JPEG 2000 codestream
```

I was able to open the generated `bug.j2k` using either IrfanView and [kdu_show](http://kakadusoftware.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/KDU78_Demo_Apps_for_Win32_160226.msi_.zip), but as you can see the image is very dark (only the lower bits are read).

Comment: But as I told you. The conversion is happening on and off. Sometimes it happens and sometimes it doesn't. When the conversion is successful, the JPEG file is generated and the image type is = 10. When it fails, the image writer returns false, and no file is generated, and the image reader doesn't return the value 10 for image type.

Comment: How can I know that my code is accepting only 8-bit? and how can I change my code to accept 16 bit images?